# Compile time error plugins for Php

Tags: php, plugins, compiler-construction, eclipse-plugin, compiler-errors

I know that php is a scripting language like perl.python.

But, is there a eclipse plugin which gives a error when a function taht is called doesn't exists. Or when a variable which is defined in the doesn't exists.

There are too many careless mistakes that are happening with me in a huge project.
I miss java for this.

Any compile time error plugins for Php?

Answer (score 0):

```
php -l /path/to/file
```

That's as good as it gets.

Setup [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) for debugging, better error messages, etc.

Comment: xdebug is after you run your code.. I need something before even clciking the run button!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the **[XDebug](http://xdebug.org/)** for tracking down the errors and more.

> But, is there a eclipse plugin which
>   gives a error when a function taht is
>   called doesn't exists.

Other than Xdebug, you can also check whether a function exists or not or if variable is defined or not using:

```
print function_exists('function_name');
print isset($variable_here); // for variable
print is_defind(CONSTANT_HERE); // for constant
```

I would also suggest you to go through very good tutorial at IBM:

**[Debugging Techniques For PHP Programmers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/)**

Comment: ah I am not looking for those.. remember if you code in java/c you get a error reported that the functiin name is incorrect, or teh variables  name doesn't exists. something like that